# Google Analytics Graph Values Do Not Add up to Number in Box

Tags: google-analytics

[Chart from Google Analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHv9Y.png)

As I worked on my sites monthly report for visits/trends, I noticed that the user number provided in text (value 4539) is different the the number you get when you add each day's plot point together along the blue line (value of 5110). I have the graph set for users, and also made sure the time frame for data was the same, but I am not sure what why these numbers differ so much.

Can someone explain this to me? Apparently I am an idiot.

Edit #1: This is the default settings under Reports > Audience > Overview. I have no dimensions added or anything more than just the strictly default settings.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. What exactly are the GA dimensions you are using? Please edit the question to provide this information. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

User numbers are time dependent. That is to say, a user may come back more than once in a month, and GA knows that because it's detecting the cookie dropped in their browser. So, if Person A visited your site on Monday he counts as one user, and a report for Monday counts him as that. If he comes back on Tuesday and you look at a user report just for Tuesday, he is again one user. So, in individual daily reports Person A is counted as one user, in 2 reports. If you look at a report for the week, he counts as one user, because GA knows that he was person coming back to your site twice in one week.